# Mr.Q : How to make a potion

Tags: riddle

Mr.Q got a magical potion recipe.

But he could not decipher the contents of the recipe and asked you for help.

Here is a recipe for potions.

```
1. Magical water...........50 L
2. Petal extract.........1050 ML
3. Fermented wine.........200 CC
4. ......................1009
```

What does the last line of the recipe indicate?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The last line indicates

> Mix everything......1009 MIX

Because

> This is not 50 liters, 1050 millilitres and 200 cubic centimeters, it's actually the roman notations of the numbers, and 1009 reads as MIX. Hence my guess that the last line is just about mixing the previous ingredients.